# Getting "Not In" to Work in Rails MySQL Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models - User. Game, and Activity.  I have a view that is supposed to show games where the user has no Activity records.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the query that excludes Games that already have activity.

When I do these two versions (in the Controller), it does not work (I receive the error `undefined method 'game_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x69eab40>`)

version 1

```
def index
  if current_user
    @activities = current_user.activities.game_id
    @games = Game.where("id NOT IN (?)", @activities )
  end
end
```

version 2

```
def index
  if current_user
    @activities = current_user.activities
    @activity_ids = @activities.game_id
    @games = Game.where("id NOT IN (?)", @activity_ids )
  end
end
```

However, when I do this it works:
The controller:

```
def index
  if current_user
    @activities = current_user.activities
    @games = Game.where("id NOT IN (?)", @activities.collect {|p| p.game_id} )
  end
end
```

I'm worried about doing it this way because I'm not sure how scalable it is.  I got the idea to do it from this [question], but in along with the answers people said that this solution was not scalable (which was not an issue for that question asker).[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756165/empty-array-is-null-in-rails-where-find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is not in that line. what's causing your error is this

```
@activities = current_user.activities.game_id
```

`current_user.activities` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so calling `game_id` on it raises an exception.  Your solution that works is fine since you're going to use `@activities` (you're going to, right?).  If you want a more sql approach, try

```
def index
  if current_user
    @activities = current_user.activities
    @games = Game.where("id NOT IN (?)", @activities.uniq.pluck(:game_id))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  All I'm using activities for is to exclude the game_id's from the current_user's Activities.  Will I have performance issues if a user ends up with thousands of Activity records, if I stick with my code that works?

Comment: I'd go with pluck in that case.  You can use joins but I think you'd have to write raw sql in order for that to work since you want to get the games that are not included in the activities.

Comment: When I try to use pluck, I'm getting the error 'undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x6f81fc0>'

Comment: that means `current_user.activities` is an array. how do you get activities for the current_user? is it an association or do you build the list of activities manually?

Comment: weird. what rails version are you using? pluck was only introduced last rails 3.2.1

Comment: just tested it out and you're right. i need to call scoped to make it work.  `current_user.activities.scoped.uniq.pluck(:game_id)`